# Подключил библиотеку opencv, но код по каким-то причинам не работает

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

Я подключил библиотеку opencv в Visual Studio(язык с++)
Начал потихоньку изучать эту библиотеку[image: введите сюда описание изображения] по Гари Брадски и Адриану Кейлеру(Learning OpenCV). Один из первых примеров было вывод картинки на экран. Я написал весь код, но по каким-то причинам компилятор не принимает его, при этом он не жалуется на "инклуды". В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Как вы подключали? В обозреватель решений в ссылках она отображается?

Comment: В ссылках нету. В свойствах проекта, во вкладке С/С++ -> Общие, в "Дополнительные каталоги включаемых" я прописал путь C:\opencv\build\include (opencv у меня находится по пути C:\opencv), потом во вкладке Компоновщик -> Общие, в "Дополнительные каталоги библиотек", я прописал C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib, ну и во вкладке Компоновщик -> Ввод, в "Дополнительные зависимости" я про прописал 2 библиотеки: opencv_world410d.lib и 
opencv_world410.lib
Во всех видео, что я смотрел, именно таким образом подключали opencv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы плохо читали, вот у вас и ошибки. Данный код, написан для `C`, не `C++`.

Отрывок из вашей книги.

> All the program examples in this book are based on OpenCV version 2.0.

Тоесть вам нужно использовать не `OpenCV 4.1.0`, а `OpenCV 2.4.13.6`, которая является последней версией, которую вы можете использовать с данными примерами кода из вашей книги.

И ещё, `opencv_world410d.lib` для `Debug`, а `opencv_world410.lib` для `Release`

Comment: Хорошо, я понял. Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @Vanya, если вам помог мой ответ, то справа моего ответа, есть галочка, нажмите её, чтобы подтвердить мой ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Namespace cv нет. Добавь using namespace cv;